# How to get clean ASP.Net error pages?

Tags: asp.net, iis, xhtml

When I get an application error with an ASP.Net(3.5) site on IIS(6.0), I get dirty HTML code.

I would like to have **auto generated XHTML code** instead, it would be nice for web services which parse answer... (I am not interested by writing custom pages).

Is there a way to specify it ?

**EDIT : EXAMPLE**

Here is for example, the generated page for a 404 error, I would like clean XHTML code instead but I do not want to write it myself, can ASP.Net module do it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>La ressource est introuvable.</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Erreur du serveur dans l'application '/</b>/MyVirtualDirectory'.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>La ressource est introuvable.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description : </b>HTTP 404. ...
            <br><br>

            <b> URL demandée: </b>/MyVirtualDirectory/MyService.aspx<br><br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Informations sur la version :</b>&nbsp;Version Microsoft .NET Framework :2.0.50727.3053; Version ASP.NET :2.0.50727.3634

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I guess, the above HTML was generated by an ASPX page, is there a place where I can find it? To get inpired and translate it in XHTML then I will use @Remko 3rd solution to specify a custom error page.

Comment: You don't have a separate response type for other web services?

Answer (score 10):

There several ways to handle errors in ASP.NET and to control the contents of your response.
Note: All methods require you to write your own custom XHTML code (despite your remark that that you're not interested in writing custom pages)

1. At page level: Add a Page_Error event handler to your page.

   ```
   public void Page_Error(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
       Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
       Response.Write("<p>Your perfectly formatted XHTML code.</p>");
       Server.ClearError();
   }
   ```

   If you call `Server.ClearError()` the error will not be handled by ASP.NET and you won't get the default error page.
2. At application level: Add a Application_Error event handler to the Global.asax.

   ```
   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
       Response.Write("<p>Your perfectly formatted XHTML code.</p>");
       Server.ClearError();
   }
   ```
3. Specify custom error pages in your `web.config` file

   ```
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="myperfectxhtmlerror.aspx" >
   ```

For more detailed explanations see: [How to create custom error reporting pages in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I will use the 3rd solution when I find the default error page and translate it to XHTML (see EDIT)

Answer (score 3):

Other than the pretty much spot on answer above you could try:

[HTTP Module for Custom Errors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16171/An-HTTP-Module-for-ASP-NET-Error-Handling)

Using this you can specify the output HTML, while this way doesn't require full custom pages it will still require you to write a small amount of HTML.